# Register a new user on wooCommerce using Rest API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin, user-registration, wp-signup

So,

I am building a website in react using Wordpress headless server with WooCommerce plugin.

I have found that to create a new customer, you have to use the WooCommerce API: `https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-customer`

But this is only creating a new customer.

What I need is to let the user to be able to register its account through a signup to become a customer. So I was planning to use: `https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/`

So my use case is to have the signup pop-up coming up and entering the name, password and email and then it create an account on Wordpress and the user become a customer for WooCommerce.

Do I have to do :

1- Create an account with Wordpress API to register the new user.

2- Create a customer using the WooCommerce API

My concerns is that how do I make sure that the user newly created is also a new customer. I do not want to have 2 differents user.

Regards
Sebastien

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think a WooCommerce customer is just a WordPress user with role 'customer'. So I'm not sure what the difference is between using the WooCommerce API and the WordPress API here? (Generally new WordPress users are emailed a new password, they don't choose them anymore, but I don't know if WooCommerce does that differently.)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new customer using the WooCommerce REST API, it will create a new WordPress user of the role Customer. Email is unique, a new customer cannot be added if his/her email is used by another WordPress user whether a customer or not. I tested that using API.

Regarding password, I still did not receive an email with it. I have my own WP deployment, and still no email is working.

What I need to look for next is how to authenticate a customer using the API to grant my customers thought my app.

Comment: "I have my own WP deployment, and still no email is working." - how have you set up email? By default WordPress will try and send to a local SMTP server I think to relay on, which you probably don't have, so at the very least you'll need to configure that to use an SMTP server provided by your host. Or I find it simpler to use a third-party mail API plugin instead.

Comment: But you've posted this as an answer to Seb's question whereas it sounds like this is actually another request for help?

Comment: "What I need to look for next is how to authenticate a customer using the API" - recent WordPress added per-user application passwords for this, or there are good plugins to do this already e.g. the JWT plugin is popular I think. Or AFAICR WooCommerce has its own REST API authentication built in too.

Comment: My first paragraph was answering his question. I added it as an answer because I tested it myself on my API, so I wanted him to know. Because I'm still half-way in my solution, I just mentioned that.